# Forget WiFi network without admin credentials

Tags: macos, wifi, administrator

Is there a way to forget a WiFi network on MacOS without knowing the admin credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within macOS, no you can't.

If you don't unlock *System Preferences* you can't add or delete a Wi-Fi access point.

As you can see you can't select a *Preferred Network* and the `+/-` is locked.

[image: Network Preferences]

Neither can you do it from command line.

You can add a network with `sudo networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex  en0 whateverNetwork 0 WPA2 whateverPassword` but if you try to delete it without sudo - for example with `networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en0 whateverNetwork` then it will prompt you.

[image: Terminal]

The reason is that the files updated are these - they are owned by root and can not be modified by a non-admin user.  :

```
A1398% ls -la /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/*preferences*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   9323 Jan 15 15:42 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   6891 Dec 27 13:35 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   6891 Jan 15 15:42 /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist.old
```

Also note as an aside that the data that is changed when you add/remove a preferred network is encrypted.

For example `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` was updated with *wifi.ssid.77686174657665724e6574776f726b* when adding and removing access point called *whateverNetwork*.

This means that if you booted from external OS to edit these files you would have to guess which keys to delete although in my limited testing they do appear to be in the same order as shown in *System Preferences*.

Comment: Thank you. Could I potentially change the SSID name or password without admin credentials, so that the laptop at least fails to connect to it and goes on to try other networks?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can forget a network on a Mac without admin privileges. You can forget the network by deleting the password from your Keychain Manager.

Comment: Worked well, Thanks

Comment: Was trying to help someone on a locked-down company laptop do this, but for some reason, the network was added to KeyChain but under his user account, which we were able to remove, but then again as admin. Is this normal?

Comment: @FrankRiccobono that might have been caused by some corporate software, especially if the computer login is the same as the wifi password